# Three ARIMA questions

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm learning ARIMA algorithm and ran into a few problems. Please answer the following questions. The ARIMA implementation used is from statesmodel.tsa.

Q1. Can the ARIMA algorithm be configured to make predictions anyway, instead of stopping, when it detects the AR cofficients are not stationary. I have the following code:

```
history = [x for x in train]
for tt in test.index:
    t=datetime.date(tt)
    # fit model
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,1,1))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    # one step forecast
    yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
    # store forecast and ob
    predictions.append(yhat)
    history.append(test[t])
```

Most of the datasets would run through the code, even though they may not produce good results. There was one set of data that caused the algorithm to stop. I examined this dataset and found its values went up first and then went down. The error message I received is as follows:

```
ValueError: The computed initial AR coefficients are not stationary. You should induce stationarity, choose a different model order, or you can pass your own start_params.
```

Q2: How should one handle time series data that has increasing values first and then the values decrease?

Q3: I then implemented a grid search to find the best (p, d, q) parameters first, by using the training data. Then this set of parameters are used in ARIMA to predict the data in the test set. However, when the data in the test set has different properties, ARIMA would stop as well. For example, with one dataset, I got (0, 0, 2) from the training data. But using this set of parameters, I received the following error message when it was used to predict the test set.

```
ValueError: The computed initial MA coefficients are not invertible. You should induce invertibility, choose a different model order, or you can pass your own start_params.
```

What are the recommended approaches for handling this type of problems?